# OpenGL Frustum mathematical understanding

Tags: opengl, matrix, 3d

I have a question pertaining to the mathematical aspect of frustum. The matrix constructed by glFrustum(l,r,b,t,n,f) I understand that l,r is essentially the x axis, b,t is y and n,f is z. Now my question is given the classic frustum matrix : http://csc.lsu.edu/~kooima/articles/genperspective/eq5.svg

I want to find the view coordinates X,Y and Z of point p=(x,y,z)
and in the special case that l=b=-1 r=t=1 and to find X,Y,Z for p(x,y-n) and p(x,y,-f)

I'm just having a hard time understanding how to do this with such abstract numbers. I know that if n=f or n or f is less than zero there's an error. But i just dont understand necessarily what I'm being asked.

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132077/clarifying-the-meaning-of-view-coordinates-from-glfrustum-opengl.

Comment: Hi, I have deduced something about frustum
https://sites.google.com/site/burlachenkok/articles/projection_matrix_opengl

Use google translate to retrieve some kind of translation
https://translate.google.ru/translate?hl=ru&sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fburlachenkok%2Farticles%2Fprojection_matrix_opengl

Answer (score 0):

Let *r* be a coordinate vector in eye space of the form *r = (x,y,z,1)*

Let *P* be a frustum transformation matrix. This allows to to transform *r* into a position *r'* in *clip sapce* by applying the transformation, which for vectors and matrices can be done using a [matrix-vector](http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication) multiplication *r' = P · r*

The normalized viewport coordinate *r''* (without clipping) is then obtained by applying the homogenous perspective division *r'' = r' / r'.w*

That's it, there's nothing more to it than that.